# Meaning of `-exec mv -f` in bash script

Tags: bash

I have come across the following line in a bash script

```
  find -type f -exec mv -f {} ${BASE_DIR}/{} \;
```

I know the meaning of the first part, it finds all the objects of type file. What does the second part `-exec mv -f {} ${BASE_DIR}/{} \;` mean

Answer (score 0):

The `-exec` option allows you to execute some code on the result of `find`, where `{}` stands for the result.

This command finds all the files and moves them to some directory defined by `$BASE_DIR`.

Comment: Yes, and the "-f" flag means "force" - that is files at destination will be overwritten without asking. This might be an important detail to the OP... :o